# C++ program attempting to double dealloc custom object

Tags: c++

#### For future visitors

It turns out I didn't have a copy assignment operator defined in my custom class, and therefore the compiler defaulted to "copy the object's pointer" behavior.

If you're confused about what a copy assignment operator is, just like I was, [this resource may help you figure out what a "copy assignment operator" looks like in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator).

The original problem prompt is below. (Links to the original source code will expire in a month; sorry!)

---

I'm working on a console application which simulates a bookstore, but keep on getting a `_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` error message in my program during execution. After doing some searching around (and some frustrating debugging), I've come to the conclusion that my object's destructor is getting called twice. I hope the code snippets below will make it a little clearer what I mean. (Clicking on the file names will open a pastie with the relevant code for easier reading/decluttering.)

---

#### [bookdata.h](http://pastebin.com/SaJeZdis)

```
#ifndef BOOKDATA_H
#define BOOKDATA_H

class bookData {
  private:
    char* bookTitle;
    char* isbn;
    char* author;
    char* publisher;
    char* dateAdded;
    int qtyOnHand;
    double wholesale;
    double retail;
  
  public:
    bookData();
    bookData(char* title, char* isbn, char* author, char* publisher, char* date, int qty, double wholesale, double retail);
    bookData(bookData& book); // Meant to be called during memberwise assignment
    ~bookData();

    // Various setter & getter funcs
};

#endif
```

---

#### [bookData.cpp](http://pastebin.com/wEFetJ3L)

```
#include "globals.h"
#include "bookData.h"

using namespace std;

// Variables in caps are const ints defined in globals.h 
 
bookData::bookData() {
  bookTitle = new char[TITLE_LENGTH];
  isbn = new char[ISBN_LENGTH];
  author = new char[AUTHOR_LENGTH];
  publisher = new char[PUBLISHER_LENGTH];
  dateAdded = new char[DATE_LENGTH];
  qtyOnHand = 0;
  wholesale = 0;
  retail = 0;

  char emptyTitle[2];
  emptyTitle[0] = '\0';
  setTitle(emptyTitle);
}

// Other constructors are overloaded version of bookData & copy data;
// See example setter function below destructor

bookData::~bookData() {
  if (bookTitle)
    delete [] bookTitle;
  else
    return;
  delete [] isbn;
  delete [] author;
  delete [] publisher;
  delete [] dateAdded;
}

// Setter functions are of this form (excl. ints & doubles)
void bookData::setTitle(const char* input) {
  for (int len = 0; len < TITLE_LENGTH - 1; len++) {
    *(bookTitle + len) = *(input + len);
    if (*(input + len) == '\0')
      break;
    else if (len == TITLE_LENGTH - 2)
      *(bookTitle + ++len) = '\0';
  }
}

// Getter functions are of this form (excl. ints & doubles)
const char* bookData::getTitle() { return bookTitle; }
```

---

#### [reports.cpp (the file that's calling the destructor twice)](http://pastebin.com/V6sdfqHJ)

```
void repQty() {
  
  // Again, variables in all caps are defined in globals.h if you don't see 
  // their declaration
  bookData bookArray[MAX_RECORDS];
  
  // Global function which populates bookArray from a datafile
  bookData* books = getBooks(bookArray);

  // Some code to find the memory address of the first and last book in the records
  bookData* HEAD = books;
  // Keep advancing until books no longer points to a non-empty bookData object
  // "Empty" defined as book's bookTitle variable starting with '\0'
  bookData* TAIL = --books;
  
  // Need all 3 pointers for a naive, in place insertion/linear sort routine
  // Outputs book data following the sort
  
  // Before returning, calls the destructors for the books in bookArray
  // Also calls the destructor for books, HEAD, and TAIL as well
  // ...which were already called as part of the bookArray's destructor calls
  // Which is where I have my problem now
}
```

---

#### Bonus: [globals.h](http://pastebin.com/V6sdfqHJ)

As you may have noticed, I've already attempted to check whether the `bookData` object has already been deleted by using `if (bookTitle)` in the destructor function, but it still evaluates as true when I'm running it through VS's Step Into functionality. Short of nuking the destructor all together, what can I do to get around this problem and make the destructor prematurely exit if the object in question has already been deallocated?

Comment: I feel like I should add that I've already searched around and found answers along the lines of "the `delete` operator only changes `bookTitle`'s memory address to a random one", then strongly suggest against manually setting `bookTitle`'s new memory address to `NULL`. I'm at a loss for what I should do, though - I've already been looking for 2-3 hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: If the control flow enters the destructor of an already-destroyed object, it's a bit late to do anything about it. You need to make sure it doesn't happen.

Comment: @n.m. I would love to halt the control flow and not have the destructor called at all (or at least stop execution after exiting the function), but C++ does it automatically. I've already looked into it, but I don't want to start any bad coding habits since I've only picked up C++ recently.

Comment: Too late. You already have plenty of bad coding habits (like using `new` and `delete` everywhere, which seems to be a source of problems.)

Comment: C++ does not call the destructor automatically for an already destroyed object. Only you can do that, if you use `delete` on something that has alrady been deleted.

Comment: @n.m. I'm already aware that [C strings and arrays are inferior to `std::string` and `std::vector`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674183/c-program-attempting-to-double-dealloc-custom-object#comment-43763459); I'm required to use them. In addition, I'm not calling the destructor manually; instead, it's automatically called once the function's scope is closed - though I am making `delete` calls in the destructor. I'll look up the other stuff, though, since I wasn't aware of them before.

Comment: @juanchopanza Any tips then? I come from a predominantly Java and Python background, which come with built-in garbage collection routines, so I have little idea what is considered "good" practice when it comes to C/C++.

Comment: Even if you can't use `std::string` or `std::vector`, I suggest following the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and factor out memory management into a different, re-usable class. Then use that in your `booData`. Basically, write a string-like class that can be safely constructed, copied, assigned and manages its own resources.

Comment: "it's automatically called once the function's scope is closed". Then it's only being called once. You don't need to check if it has already been called, since that can't happen (and you can't check anyway). I see the problem has been resolved with the copy assignment operator. This also means that checking the pointer at hand would have been useless. The string was being deleted through a different pointer (you used to have two book objects pointing to same strings). Your pointer was still keeping its original value, but was pointing to a non-existing object, and you can't check for that.

Comment: @juanchopanza n.m. Thanks for the explanations and suggestions; I'll give it a shot once I'm done with this assignment/project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've already attempted to check whether the `bookData` object has already been deleted by using if (`bookTitle`) in the destructor function

Since `delete[]` doesn't set the pointer to `NULL`, the check is effectively a no-op.

Even if you set the pointer to `NULL` manually, you'd be tackling the symptoms of the problem rather than the root cause.

The root cause is that you're not implementing the copy assignment operator, thereby violating the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). What happens is that you're using the implicitly-generated copy assignment operator:

```
  swap = *books;
  *books = *(books - 1);
  *(books - 1) = swap;
```

and that operator doesn't do the right thing: it copies the pointers instead of copying the data. The double deletes are a direct consequence of that.

Additionally, the implementation of the copy constructor could be buggy, but it's hard to be sure without seeing its source code.

P.S. You'd do yourself a massive favour by using `std::string` instead of C strings. Also, `std::vector` is to be preferred to C arrays.

Comment: You replied just [as I posted a comment addressing that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674183/c-program-attempting-to-double-dealloc-custom-object#comment-43763325). I just can't think of another way around it, as Vis Studio shows that the data address has been changed when I debug.

Comment: Full code of the copy constructor can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/wEFetJ3L), but I don't think it's buggy. Also, I've seen the Rule of Three mentioned a few time already, but I'm not sure which I'm missing - it appears to be the copy assignment operator, but I'm not entirely clear on what that is.

Comment: @Edwin: Google "copy assignment operator" (sometimes referred to less precisely as simply the "assignment operator"). For example, here is a tutorial: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/. In a nutshell, you need to implement one and you need to make sure it is correct.

Comment: I would love to use `std::string` over C strings, but I'm required to use them. Same with `std::vector`. I'll take a look again though - I *think* I have an idea of what a copy assignment operator is now.

Comment: Thanks; managed to solve the problem with your help. For future visitors, [this resource may help you figure out what a "copy assignment operator" looks like in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator).